# CSS hover should rotate vertical text to horizontal

Tags: css

I would like a vertically aligned text to rotate in the horizontal direction when it is hovered. As an animation. Unfortunately I can't get any further at the moment. It is about the link on the right ("back"). Who knows how to do it? Thanks for advance!

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 3px #ccc;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
}    
#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
}
#nav a {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--text-color)
}

#nav a {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#nav a:hover {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <a href="/">back</a>      
</div>
<div class="container">123</div>
```

Comment: Well first of all, you're rotating the link by the same 180deg, so hover doesn't do anything. Try with 270deg on hover

Comment: For animation you could add `transition: transform 1s ease-in;` for example

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković super! but now i need that it rotate smove as animation.

Comment: There are many transition functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković SuperCool! That was exactly what i wanted!? genius!

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković and if i hover out i can make it transition back same as hover in? smove.

Comment: That's already happening by default: https://jsfiddle.net/6xm45tj2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240216/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-roberto-zvjerkovic).

Answer (score 1):

The `display` property has to be changed to `block` for the `transform` to work. You don’t need to change the direction when the `transform` works. You can set the `transform` to `initial` on `:hover` and set `transition` for the animation.

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 3px #ccc;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
}    
#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
}
#nav a {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: .3s;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--text-color)
}

#nav a:hover {
  transform: initial;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <a href="/">back</a>      
</div>
<div class="container">123</div>
```